# Argument string that applies different code expressions based on the specified option

Tags: arguments

I want to pass an argument string to `\NewDocumentCommand` that allows me to apply  different code expressions based on the specified option.

For instance, consider a command named `product` with an argument called `type` , where the latter can be either `"direct"` (in such case printing `$#2 \times #3$`) or `"tensor"` (in such printing `$#2 \otimes #3$`).

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a minimal but complete example people can compile to help you? I don't understand what you mean by 'an argument called `type`'. Do you just want `\NewDocumentCommand {mmm}` and then test if `#1` is `direct` or `tensor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xstring` package to do such conditions:

The `\Product` defined below takes an option for parameter (defaults to "direct" if not specified. You need to decide how to handle the error condition.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Product}{O{direct} m m}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {direct}{#2 \times  #3}%
        {tensor}{#2 \otimes #3}%
    }[%
        \text{Unsupported case: #1.}%
    ]%
}

\begin{document}
$\Product{a}{b}$

$\Product[direct]{a}{b}$

$\Product[tensor]{a}{b}$

$\Product[wacky]{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use l3 layer for this. `texdoc interface3` to get the user guide.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \l_my_command:n #1
  {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{#1}
    \str_case_e:nnTF {\l_tmpa_tl}  
    {

               { none       } {               } 
               { rmfamily   } {  \rmfamily    } 
               { serif      } {   \rmfamily   } 
               { sans-serif } {  \sffamily    } 
               { sans       } {  \sffamily    }
               { sffamily   } {  \sffamily    }
               { ttfamily   } {  \ttfamily    } 
           
               { mono       } {  \ttfamily    } 
   }                 
               {  TRUE~                            }
               {  FALSE~                           }
    
  }

\l_my_command:n {mono    }  some~text\par

\l_my_command:n {rmfamily}   some~text

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCommand}{ m }
{
    \l_my_command:n{#1}  
}  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\MyCommand{mono}  Some other text

\end{document}
```